# PCManFM-QT, Dolphin, FTP, and upload/overwrite prompts

Tags: kubuntu, qt, ftp, pcmanfm-qt

In the previous version of ubuntu, PCManFM-QT would not prompt to upload/overwrite remote files when editing in VSCode using PCManFM-QT as my FTP client. I've updated to Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS, and now PCManFM-QT is prompting to upload, then overwrite remote files. (Dolphin has always prompted.)

Please help me to understand what's going on here: is this a function of the OS or the file manager? Is there a way to stop the behavior? Is there a graphical FTP client that doesn't prompt (in the same way as WinSCP)?

Comment: You mention two programs `pcmanfm` which is a GTK2 app (from LXDE desktop), & `pcmanfm-qt` which is a Qt5 app (LXQt desktop) as if they're the same; but they different apps. Yes the developer who created it ([PcMan](https://github.com/PCMan)) is the same person, but `pcmanfm-qt` is a different app intended to replace the original one. Are you confusing those two different applications?  Please also be clear as to what release you mean; ie. 22.04 & 21.10? or something else

Comment: Also, I just remembered the version of `pcmanfm-qt` used in both Ubuntu 21.10 & Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is the same (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pcmanfm-qt&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) unless you've opted to add the later version available via the [Lubuntu backports PPA](https://lubuntu.me/jammy-backports-22-04-1/) so no change has occurred in the `pcmanfm-qt` app itself between 21.10 & 22.04  *I don't know about `pcmanfm` as that's been a purely upstream Debian provided package since 18.10*

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: it's PCManFM-QT, always. Ubuntu is Studio 22.04. But here's an additional piece of information from this morning: Kate doesn't do this, only VSCode. So I'm guessing not a PCManFM-QT issue. (This is a shame because all of my AutoKey shortcuts are written for VSCode and Kate lacks a few features that would be very useful.)

Comment: Please correct your question then, as `pcmanfm` and `pcmanfm-qt` are different programs, with different features (newer features were added to `pcmanfm-qt`) using different *libs*, your question currently mentions both.  `kate` is a KDE app thus uses KF5, `pcmanfm-qt` is the LXQt desktop app so only uses Qt5 (no KF5 is used by LXQt though Lubuntu use some Qt5/KF5/KDE apps thus parts are included in Lubuntu). I don't know about 3rd party vscode.